# Adding a generated column to the end of a SQL query results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to figure out if I can use SQL to generate an artificial column.

Given the fake data below, how could you create a generated column called `GENERATED_SEQUENCE`.

The rules would be as follows:

- must be in the same course (Id)
- must be on the same date (Course_Date)
- each course session must be within 30 minutes of each other (Course_Start_Time and Course_End_Time)

Code:

```
select 
    111 As Id, 'Bio 101' As Course_Name, 
    '1/10/2016' AS Course_Date, 
    '09:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
    '09:45:00' AS Course_End_Time, 
    1 AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE

union all

select
    111 As Id, 'Bio 101' As Course_Name, 
    '1/10/2016' AS Course_Date, 
    '10:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,  
    '010:45:00' AS Course_End_Time, 
    2 AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE 

union all

select
    111 As Id, 'Bio 101' As Course_Name, 
    '1/10/2016' AS Course_Date, 
    '11:05:00' AS Course_Start_Time, 
    '12:30:00' AS Course_End_Time, 
    3 AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE

union all

select
    431 As Id, 'Econ 101' As Course_Name, 
    '1/12/2016' AS Course_Date, 
    '11:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
    '12:45:00' AS Course_End_Time, 
    1 AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE 

union all

select
    111 As Id, 'Bio 101' As Course_Name, 
    '1/12/2016' AS Course_Date, 
    '1:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time, 
    '2:45:00' AS Course_End_Time, 
    1 AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE 

union all

select
    543 As Id, 'Eng 200' As Course_Name, 
    '1/13/2016' AS Course_Date, 
    '2:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time, 
    '2:45:00' AS Course_End_Time, 
    1 AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE 

union all

select
    543 As Id, 'Eng 200' As Course_Name, 
    '1/13/2016' AS Course_Date, 
    '2:55:00' AS Course_Start_Time, 
    '3:55:00' AS Course_End_Time, 
    2 AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE 

union all

select
    543 As Id, 'Eng 200' As Course_Name, 
    '1/14/2016' AS Course_Date, 
    '6:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time, 
    '8:15:00' AS Course_End_Time, 
    1 AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems possible. It could involve a `partition` on `Course_Name` and `Course_Date`, `order by Course_Start_Time`, perhaps a `lead`/`lag` and `DateDiff`. Something about _islands and gaps_. Give it a try and see what you come up with. Post it and any _specific_ problem(s) and we'll help you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using a CTE for your data and a RANK() and LEAD() function.

```
WITH cteCourse
AS (SELECT 111 AS Id,
           'Bio 101' AS Course_Name,
           '1/10/2016' AS Course_Date,
           '09:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
           '09:45:00' AS Course_End_Time
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 111 AS Id,
           'Bio 101' AS Course_Name,
           '1/10/2016' AS Course_Date,
           '10:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
           '10:45:00' AS Course_End_Time
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 111 AS Id,
           'Bio 101' AS Course_Name,
           '1/10/2016' AS Course_Date,
           '11:05:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
           '12:30:00' AS Course_End_Time
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 431 AS Id,
           'Econ 101' AS Course_Name,
           '1/12/2016' AS Course_Date,
           '11:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
           '12:45:00' AS Course_End_Time
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 111 AS Id,
           'Bio 101' AS Course_Name,
           '1/12/2016' AS Course_Date,
           '13:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
           '14:45:00' AS Course_End_Time
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 543 AS Id,
           'Eng 200' AS Course_Name,
           '1/13/2016' AS Course_Date,
           '14:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
           '14:45:00' AS Course_End_Time
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 543 AS Id,
           'Eng 200' AS Course_Name,
           '1/13/2016' AS Course_Date,
           '14:55:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
           '15:55:00' AS Course_End_Time
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 543 AS Id,
           'Eng 200' AS Course_Name,
           '1/14/2016' AS Course_Date,
           '18:00:00' AS Course_Start_Time,
           '20:15:00' AS Course_End_Time)
SELECT Id,
       Course_Name,
       Course_Date,
       Course_Start_Time,
       Course_End_Time,
       CASE
           WHEN Course_End_Time + '00:30:00' <= LEAD(Course_Start_Time, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Course_Name,
                                                                                             Course_Date,
                                                                                             Course_Start_Time,
                                                                                             Course_End_Time
                                                                                   ) THEN
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id,
                                         Course_Date
                            ORDER BY Course_Start_Time,
                                     Course_End_Time
                           )
           ELSE
               1
       END AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE
FROM cteCourse;
```

Answering your question below, you can turn the second query into a CTE and query from it like a table. For example:

```
,cteGenSeq AS (
SELECT Id,
       Course_Name,
       Course_Date,
       Course_Start_Time,
       Course_End_Time,
       CASE
           WHEN Course_End_Time + '00:30:00' <= LEAD(Course_Start_Time, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Course_Name,
                                                                                             Course_Date,
                                                                                             Course_Start_Time,
                                                                                             Course_End_Time
                                                                                   ) THEN
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id,
                                         Course_Date
                            ORDER BY Course_Start_Time,
                                     Course_End_Time
                           )
           ELSE
               1
       END AS GENERATED_SEQUENCE
FROM cteCourse
)

SELECT * FROM cteGenSeq
```

Comment: would it be possible to actually add the 'GENERATED_SEQUENCE' column to the CTE so that additional queries could be used against the full set of data?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Are you saying you'd like to run additional queries against the CTE but can't because it's already used as part of the ranking query?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way, to slightly modify your working answer, to include the CTE and the newly generated column called GENERATED_SEQUENCE into another CTE or temp table...

Comment: Yes, definitely. I edited my answer above to show how to turn the second query into a CTE and query from it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option.

Sub-query using:

- LAG() on Course_End_Date so we can use that in DATEDIFF() to determine the number of minutes the previous course had finished.
- Evaluated that with a case statement to determine if we are within 30 minutes as a new column called [PrevCourseWithIn30]

From there you can then simply use the ROW_NUMBER() window function and partition by Id, Course_Date and our new [PrevCourseWithIn30] column to get your new [GENERATED_SEQUENCE] column

Have a look at this:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [Id] INT
      , [Course_Name] NVARCHAR(100)
      , [Course_Date] DATE
      , [Course_Start_Time] TIME
      , [Course_End_Time] TIME
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [Id]
                        , [Course_Name]
                        , [Course_Date]
                        , [Course_Start_Time]
                        , [Course_End_Time]
                      )
            SELECT 111 AS [Id]
                 , 'Bio 101' AS [Course_Name]
                 , '2016-01-10' AS [Course_Date]
                 , '09:00:00' AS [Course_Start_Time]
                 , '09:45:00' AS [Course_End_Time]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 111 AS [Id]
                 , 'Bio 101' AS [Course_Name]
                 , '2016-01-10' AS [Course_Date]
                 , '10:00:00' AS [Course_Start_Time]
                 , '10:45:00' AS [Course_End_Time]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 111 AS [Id]
                 , 'Bio 101' AS [Course_Name]
                 , '2016-01-10' AS [Course_Date]
                 , '11:05:00' AS [Course_Start_Time]
                 , '12:30:00' AS [Course_End_Time]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 431 AS [Id]
                 , 'Econ 101' AS [Course_Name]
                 , '2016-01-12' AS [Course_Date]
                 , '11:00:00' AS [Course_Start_Time]
                 , '12:45:00' AS [Course_End_Time]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 111 AS [Id]
                 , 'Bio 101' AS [Course_Name]
                 , '2016-01-12' AS [Course_Date]
                 , '1:00:00' AS [Course_Start_Time]
                 , '2:45:00' AS [Course_End_Time]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 543 AS [Id]
                 , 'Eng 200' AS [Course_Name]
                 , '2016-01-13' AS [Course_Date]
                 , '2:00:00' AS [Course_Start_Time]
                 , '2:45:00' AS [Course_End_Time]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 543 AS [Id]
                 , 'Eng 200' AS [Course_Name]
                 , '2016-01-13' AS [Course_Date]
                 , '2:55:00' AS [Course_Start_Time]
                 , '3:55:00' AS [Course_End_Time]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 543 AS [Id]
                 , 'Eng 200' AS [Course_Name]
                 , '2016-01-14' AS [Course_Date]
                 , '6:00:00' AS [Course_Start_Time]
                 , '8:15:00' AS [Course_End_Time];


SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [CS].[Id]
                                      , [CS].[Course_Date]
                                      , [CS].[PrevCourseWithIn30]
                           ORDER BY [CS].[Course_Start_Time]
                         ) AS [GENERATED_SEQUENCE]
FROM   (
           SELECT *
                , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(
                                        MINUTE
                                      , LAG(
                                              [Course_End_Time]
                                            , 1
                                            , [Course_Start_Time]
                                          ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [Id]
                                                              , [Course_Date]
                                                   ORDER BY [Course_Start_Time]
                                                 )
                                      , [Course_Start_Time]
                                    ) <= 30 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                  END AS [PrevCourseWithIn30]
           FROM   @TestData
       ) AS [CS];
```